# Php Javascript Div Refresh

Tags: php, javascript, reload

I'm refreshing a div every 20 seconds on a page. The code refreshes the div but also nests a div inside of itself.

```
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
  $("#open").load("test.php #open");
  }, 20000);
</script>
```

Before javascript reload:

```
<div id="open">
  <p>Testing</p>
</div>
```

After javascript reload:

```
<div id="open">
    <div id="open">
        <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

No matter how long the page sites there it will always just have one nested div after the javascript runs. How do I get this to not load another nested div?

Comment: You should use a different ID name per DIV imo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, There is only one div with the id "open" on this page

Comment: Why do you have `.load(test.php #open)` and not just `.load(test.php)`? You're saying to get `test.php` and then take whatever is in `#open` in that file, and then add it to your current page. That's why you have nested `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

I presume test.php returns `<div id="open">(blah)</div>`?

Try:

```
$("#open").load("test.php #open").children( ).unwrap( );
```

Although you should really change the php script.